# MongoDB authentication on some databases but not others

Tags: mongodb

I can successfully set up authentication and use it with mongoDB. The issue i'm currently having is that I can't work out how to have authentication set for one database, but not others. For instance, if my databases are:

```
admin
authenticatedDB
openDB
```

I would like authenticatedDB to require authentication, whereas I'd like openDB to be freely accessible with no login. Is this possible within MongoDB?

If it's not possible, is there a way to run two separate mongod sessions locally?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue i'm currently having is that I can't work out how to have authentication set for one database, but not others.

Auth (as at MongoDB 2.4) is a global setting, so will be required for all connections once you have [enabled authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) and created a [user administrator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/).

> If it's not possible, is there a way to run two separate mongod sessions locally?

You can run [multiple instances](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/) on the same server by specifying different `data` directories and `port` values for each `mongod`.  This is definitely not a recommended practice for production environments as multiple mongods will be competing for the same host resources.

As an alternative to running multiple `mongods`, you could use weak credentials for your openDB (i.e. username and password `openDB`).  Access control in MongoDB 2.4+ uses [user privilege roles](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/user-privileges/) so your openDB user could be limited to `read` or `readWrite` role on the `openDB` database.